# Web scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup can't catch all source code

Tags: python, web-scraping

I already saw the others questions about web scraping and python, but there is a case where there is no answer yet.

With 'requests' and 'BeautifulSoup' we can get the source code, but some parts are missing, how can we get those 'protected' data?

Because they are present on the website, they are present in the source code, so why does Python can't catch them?

An example on this link: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL
The small table "Fair Value"

Comment: There's no table "Fair Value"; that's just an H5 header element followed by 2 divs with SVGs.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to use a slider and the way they calculate where the slider goes is most likely in an algorithm in the backend. It's impossible to extract the actual data from their DB but maybe you can create a semi-accurate calculator to determine what the weight of each pixel is. The element below is the actual tick in the slider and its position is calculated by left:calc(100% - 7px). You can make your own scale based upon theirs? Let me know where in the source code it is and I'll take a look, I could be totally wrong haha

```
<div class="Pos(a) T(-2px) W(3px) H(12px) Bdrs(4px) Bgc($primaryColor) " style="left:calc(100% - 7px);" data-reactid="199"></div>
```